# In ArcGIS there is a Erase Point tool how can this be done in R

Tags: r, erase

I have a SpatialPolygoneDataFrame and a SpatialPointsDataFrame I would like to erase the points inside of the polygon, Keeping only the points outside and all of the data. I am new to GIS in R moving from ArcGIS and arcpy.

This is what the Erase Points tool does in ArcGIS 10.4 can this be done in R
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/erase-point.htm
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sp `over` or rgeos `gIntersects` function to identify intersecting points. I chose `gIntersects` because it is somewhat faster than `over` and returns a Boolean that can be passed to `which` to return an index.

Here is a simple function for identifying and erasing points intersecting a polygon(s).

```
erase.point <- function(y, x, inside = TRUE) {
  if(inside) {
    return( y[-which(rgeos::gIntersects(y, x, byid = TRUE)),] )
  } else {
    return( y[which(rgeos::gIntersects(y, x, byid = TRUE)),] )  
  }
}
```

First, we need to create some data to test the function.

```
require(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
poly <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553, 
                                 180314, 179955, 179142, 179437, 179524, 179979, 180042), c(332373, 332026, 
                                 331426, 330889, 330683, 331133, 331623, 332152, 332357, 332373)))),'1'))), 
                                 data.frame(row.names=c('1'), PIDS=1))
```

Now call `erase.point` and plot the results. If the argument "inside" is changed to FALSE then points inside the polygon will be retained, making it consistent with the ArcGIS erase point tool.

```
meuse.erase <- erase.point(meuse, poly)      

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(meuse,pch=20)
    plot(poly,add=T)
  plot(meuse.erase,pch=20)
    plot(poly,add=T)
```